# node-csv call .on("end" from .on("record"

Tags: node.js, csv

I am using node-csv to parse csv files.

I want to call the .on("end"... part of the code when a number of records has been processed.

for example

```
csv().from("test.csv")
.on("record",function(row,index){
      if(index == 100)
      { 
     //call .on(end here
     }
})
.on("end",function(count){
       //do some post processing
});
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Call the `end()` method of the CSV parser object.

```
var mycsv = csv();
mycsv.from('test.csv')
  .on('record', function(row, index) {
    if (index === 100) {
      // Don't process any more.
      mycsv.end();
    }
    // processing your record
  })
  .on('end', function(count) {
    // post processing
  });
```